# gsub using index in lua

Tags: string, lua, gsub

Here I replace `"456"` in `"12345678-12345678"` with `"XXX"` when.

```
s1 = string.gsub("12345678-12345678", "456", "XXX")
print(s1) -- 123XXX78-123XXX78
```

I want to replace `"456"` but with index (instead of writing `"456"` I want to use index), replace from index `3` to index `5` with `"XXX"`.

Comment: `string.gsub("123456789ABCDEF", "^(...)...", "%1XXX")`?

Comment: What is %1 for?

Answer (score 1):

you can use indices to find the substring first

```
subStr = string.sub("123456789ABCDEF", 3, 5) --  345 
newStr = string.gsub("123456789ABCDEF", subStr, "XXX") -- 12XXX6789ABCDEF
```

Also string.find returns the start and end index

```
strStart, strEnd = string.find("123456789ABCDEF", "345")
print(strStart, strEnd) -- 3, 5
```

Comment: I thought of this way but my actual string something like "1234,1234,1234,1234" so when I sub I can't get the right subStr, though I already know the right index which I want to use.

Comment: I edited my answer, I think the only option in my case is to use index, thanks anyway xD

Comment: so you already know in `12345678-12345678` first "345" is at index [3:5] and second is [12:14]?